# Grid with Pyglet and GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I'm trying to create a grid in pyglet using GL_LINE_LOOP. However, I'm having trouble with the sequence of vertices.

One Rectangle works fine:

[image: One Rectangle works fine]

When there are more than 1 col, it looks out of control:

[image: When there are more than 1 col, it looks out of control]

Adding rows doesn't really create this problem. It's only when adding cols that things get wonky.

Here's my code generating the grid

```
 for row in range(self.rows):
    for col in range(self.cols):
        tL=(offsetX+col*self.spacingX, 0, offsetZ+row*self.spacingZ)
        tR=(offsetX+(col+1)*self.spacingX, 0, offsetZ+row*self.spacingZ)
        bL=(offsetX+col*self.spacingX, 0, offsetZ+(row+1)*self.spacingZ)
        bR=(offsetX+(col+1)*self.spacingX, 0, offsetZ+(row+1)*self.spacingZ)
        vertices = tL+tR+bR+bL
        color = (0.8,0.8,0.7)*(len(vertices)//3)
        self.Lines.add(len(vertices)//3,GL_LINE_LOOP, None,\
        ('v3f/static',vertices),('c3f/static',color)
```

I tried printing out the vertices for each row but all the sequences seem right (topRight-topLeft-btmLeft-btmRight), and I'm stuck.

Comment: Why not just a bunch of crisscrossing `GL_LINES` instead of `GL_LINE_LOOP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get odd artifacts when using `GL_LINE_LOOP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` unless you use it for it's original intent, and that is to create one object.

When you try to mash multiple "objects" into one big structure using the same vertice list object (two mentioned above) they will most likely create "connecting lines" whether you want it or not. This is because they expect to at some point attach to the original source.

I've only glanced at your math here, and I have no coordinates to try with.
But it looks like you're not drawing them based on the principle that they will always connect to the last known coordinate?

This is `GL_LINE_LOOP`:

[image]

### First option:

With this in mind, that your big square setup is actually one gigantic big connected object, you could solve it by doing this:

[image]

### Second option (separate by batch):

```
self.Lines = {}
self.Lines[0] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
self.Lines[1] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
```

And for each square (you should have four), you'd have to do:

```
self.Lines[square_ID].add(...)
```

### Third option (invoke `glBegin`):

```
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
    glVertex2f(x1, y1)
    glVertex2f(x2, y2)
    ...
    glEnd()
```

for each square you'd wish to draw up.

## Final (and best solution, use `GL_QUADS`):

```
c = (255, 255, 255, 128)

window_corners = [
    (bottom_left[0], bottom_left[1], c),    # bottom left
    (top_left[0], top_left[1], c),          # top left
    (top_right[0], top_right[1], c),        # top right
    (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1], c)   # bottom right
]

box_vl = self.pixels_to_vertexlist(window_corners)
box_vl.draw(pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I ended up using GL_LINES, but I do feel GL_QUADS is better because I'm thinking of mousing draging the points of the grid. However, how do you only show lines with GL_QUAD? I tried using glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE) but it's either not working or it just drew all of my other geometries in lines.